# iOS: Autolayout causing image frame to be smaller?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an issue where my UIImageView becomes less than the screen size when I use autolayout

ex:

storyboard:

[image]

simulator:

[image]

The method in my controller that draws the image is this:

```
- (void)updateCoasterImage:(NSString *)imageName {
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"table"]]];

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imageName]];
    CGRect screen = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(screen.origin.x,
                               screen.origin.y,
                               screen.size.width * 1.4,
                               screen.size.height * 1.2);

    self.coasterImage.frame = bounds;
    self.coasterImage.image = image;
    self.coasterImage.center = self.coasterImage.superview.center;
}
```

Why is it behaving this way? When I remove autolayout, it looks good (except for the tool icon on the top right since it doesn't stay snapped to the blue lines in the storyboard)

I thought setting the frame to the screen size would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already diagnosed the issue perfectly. Your image view's size is configured by autolayout constraints, not by its frame. Setting its frame will have no effect, because after you do, autolayout will come along and obey the constraints. To get this to work, fix the *constraints*.

Comment: thanks for the tip! it worked and made my life easier without having to set the frame

Comment: Cool! You did all the work; your analysis by testing to see what happens if autolayout was turned off allowed you to put your finger right on the issue. Well done.